# Deleted answers now invisible to authors below 10k under EL&U and SO

Tags: bug, status-completed, deleted-answers, visibility

I've just tried it again to make sure before posting this question but since one or two days at least, whenever I delete one of my answers, it becomes invisible to me.

**Evidence**

- I've just deleted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5005428/open-source-applications-built-using-xmpp/5005826#5005826) in SO. And It's now invisible.
- I usually hang around in English Language and Usage.  All the answers I've deleted over there (at least the ones I can remember) are gone.  10K users report that they can see these answers just fine.

**Question**

Is this a *deliberate* or an *unwanted* feature?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The fact that your deleted *answers* were invisible was a bug; this is already fixed. This fix was rolled out about ten minutes ago (not to Stack Overflow yet, but you should be able to see your deleted answers on English.SE).

The fact that your deleted *questions* are invisible to you has always been this way.

Comment: Was that the cause of the rolling "offline for maintenance" pages I was getting?

Comment: @ChrisF: Probably, yeah. Deploying takes the server down for a couple of seconds.

Comment: Seems to be working on StackOverflow now :-)

Comment: @Rocket, if by *working* you mean that deleted answers are back, then yes.  This is what I've just noted: my deleted answers are back. Good! I'm still a long way from 10k ;-)