# Answer is removed from page after deleting

Tags: bug, answers, deleted-answers, undelete

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Deleted answers now invisible to authors below 10k under EL&U and SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91112/deleted-answers-now-invisible-to-authors-below-10k-under-elu-and-so)

I deleted my own answer on a question.  When I went back to the question later, my answer was missing.

Usually, my answer would be there, but grayed out with a red background, but it's just not there.

If it matters, the question was: [How can I fire something after $(document).ready() completes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5994195/how-can-i-fire-something-after-document-ready-completes)

I added an answer, then deleted it, and now it's not there.

On another question: [jQuery find location.href and replace with function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5985157/jquery-find-location-href-and-replace-with-function), this same thing happened.

I added an answer, deleted it, and when I went back to the page later, the answer was missing.  I then added a new answer.  That new answer is there, but the deleted one isn't.

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/91112/156875

Comment: My expectation is that [the fix for this still hasn't been fully deployed to Stack Overflow yet](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91112/deleted-answers-now-invisible-to-authors-below-10k-under-elu-and-so).